# Text bottom-to-top in a table

Tags: css

Is there a way to rotate the text 90 degrees when inside a table:

Something like:

```
    <tr>
        <th class="bottomtop">
            <span class="bottomtop">{{ task_definition }}</span>
        </th>
    </tr>

.bottomtotop { 
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

I want the text to look like:

```
h
e
l
l
o
# with the actual letters rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is that your `span` has a class of `bottomtop`, but your CSS defines `bottomtotop`. I just added a `display:block`, and corrected the class name and it worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/c5FzT/

```
.bottomtop { 
display:block;
transform:rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like this

```
.bottomtotop { 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);   
  display:inline-block
}
```

The most important thing is that `span` is an inline element. transform doesn't work with that. So you need to use either block elements or use `display:inline-block` or `display:block`  with `span` and of-course match the class name with markup. (you mentioned *bottomtop* in your markup but in your css it is *bottomtotop*)

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmWrF/1/)